# Getting file sync status in blobfuse (Azure storage)

Tags: linux, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to check file sync status for blobfuse mount in Linux ?
Does blobfuse store this information anywhere ?
For example I have a new file that was added to blobfuse mount and would like to check whether sync process is completed.

I know that I can take filename and check if it exists in storage using PowerShell or AZcopy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed [the article](https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-df#:%7E:text=Linux%20df%20command%20is%20used%20to%20display%20the,the%20directory%20where%20the%20file%20system%20is%20mounted.) to mount Blob storage as a file system with blobfuse. You can use [df](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/df-command-in-linux-with-examples/) command to check the mount point in Linux. Then you can `cd` to that mount point, then list the files and directories with the command `ls -al` in the current mount point.

Comment: I know that I can do "ls" on the side of linux and "azcopy list" to extract list of files and the  check whether they are the same, but i thought that maybe there is some some sort of flag for sync status to check whether blobfuse finished syncing or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check the sync status. If user has written a file to blobfuse mount, as soon as user close the file from application, blobfuse will go ahead and upload the data. If you wish to check the status easier way is to set "file-cache-timeout" to "0". This means as soon as file is uploaded delete it from local cache. User can keep monitoring the local cache and any file visible in that is still no uploaded.